# C# Error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I get error every time when I debug program and trying to close program then program closes and I get this error `An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll`

And showing me I have in code something wrong.

My code:

```
void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (stop)
        {
            var proc = (Process)sender;

            stop = false; // allows you to spawn a new thread after stopping the first
            proc.SynchronizingObject = this; // puts the form in charge of async communication
            proc.Kill(); // terminates the thread
            proc.WaitForExit(); // thread is killed asynchronously, so this goes here...

        }
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            string newLine = e.Data.Trim() + Environment.NewLine;
            MethodInvoker append = () => {
                pingInformatsioon.Text += newLine;
                if (checkBox1.Checked)
                {
                    WriteLog(newLine);
                }
            };
            pingInformatsioon.BeginInvoke(append);
        }
    }
```

Always coming yellow color over `pingInformatsioon.BeginInvoke(append);` like there are something wrong..

Answer (score 1):

You are probably calling this code from threads other than UI thread. Try replacing

```
pingInformatsioon.BeginInvoke(append);
```

with something like this

```
if (InvokeRequired)
    pingInformatsioon.BeginInvoke(append);
else
    Invoke(append);
```

Comment: Error CS1501 No overload for method 'Invoke' takes 0 arguments